# delete a directory having subdirectory (not empty)

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

How can i delete a directory having subdirectory inside it which is not empty.

thanks for the answers

but now when  am deleteing any directory at run time so it will take me to the login page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use the [Directory.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx) method passing `true` as second argument.

```
Directory.Delete(@"c:\somedirectory", true);
```