# Directory is not empty error in c#

Tags: c#

In my example I am trying to delete the folders under a particular folder. My folder structure like this... `C:\Export\MyDir1\MyDir2\MyDir3\MyDir4\MyDir5` This structure will come on the fly. Next time when I run my application it should check for `C:\Export\MyDir1` directory and delete if exists. I written like this

```
private static string getExportPath(string exportTargetPath, string parentIssue)
        {
            string exportPath = Path.Combine(exportTargetPath, parentIssue);
            if (Directory.Exists(exportPath))
            {
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(exportPath);
                string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(exportTargetPath);

                File.SetAttributes(exportTargetPath, FileAttributes.Normal);
                Directory.Delete(exportTargetPath,false);
            }

            return exportPath;
        }
```

I checked with the issue posted in this sit [Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329355/cannot-delete-directory-with-directory-deletepath-true)  I tried with this one but can't get solution. As per the suggested answer for this question, when i try to iterate through the directories then it is going to infinite loop. Where I done the mistake? Could any one help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [delete a directory having subdirectory (not empty)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933764/delete-a-directory-having-subdirectory-not-empty)

Answer (score 21):

Do a recursive delete: `Directory.Delete(exportTargetPath, true);`

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx) specifically says that you will get an IOException if:

> The directory specified by path is read-only, **or recursive is false and path is not an empty directory.**

Answer (score 6):

The 2nd param of [Directory.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx) is named 'recursive' for a reason. Try setting that to true.

Comment: None of you guys are answering the question. In my case it works recursively sometimes and other times it don't. I just want to delete everything in a directory, file/folder/directory, just all!

Comment: How is this not an answer? Did you try it? What is the part we're missing? Enlighten us

Comment: Seems like Directory class doesn't like that you to have File Explorer opened on the same path you are working on, maybe that was the problem.