# Delete directory error

Tags: asp.net, directory

I do this in my code:

```
Directory.Delete(MapPath("..\\Directory1"),true);
```

Now I got this error:
System.IO.IOException: The directory is not empty.

What do I wrong anyone a idea?

Comment: probable duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/329355/284240

Comment: also check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415105/directory-is-not-empty-error-when-trying-to-programmatically-delete-a-folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to delete all files and folders inside the directory you want to delete and then delete the directory.

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo projectDetailsInfo = new DirectoryInfo(pathofyourdirectory);

foreach (FileInfo file in projectDetailsInfo.GetFiles())
{
       file.Delete();
}
foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in projectDetailsInfo.GetDirectories())
{
  dir.Delete(true);
}
Directory.Delete(path);
```

hope this will help you.